# How can I open a datepicker with a label <button> </button> without using trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to change the way buttons work. I want the `<input type = "submit">` to behave as the `<button>` does in code and the  `<button>` as `<input type = "submit">`. I think I can invert it if I know how to open the date picker with `<button>` `</button>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    //type submit
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    //type submit

    //Click buttom
    $("#div1").click(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
    });
    //Click buttom
});
</script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="div1" >13/04/2020</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="datepicker" value="CAMBIAR FECHA">
<!-- <input type="submit" id="open-datepicker" value="cambiar fecha"> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: When if feels like missing words... Open the edit mode ;)

Comment: If you really wanted too, you could make a button click a hidden `<input type="submit">`. Would this help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are having an issue with or what you are trying to accomplish. You may want to consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "13/04/2020"
  });
});
```

```css
.back {
  background: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<input type="submit" id="datepicker" value="CAMBIAR FECHA">
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I don't know how to make <button> change dynamically and in <input type = submit> it remains static

Comment: You would need to adjust the `.val()` on the `input`.